# form is not submitted on enter key when there is no submit button inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is there some fix for this

```
<form>
<input type="text" ...

</form>
```

hitting the enter key inside the textfield when there is no submit button inside doesn't submit the form, is there some fix for this ?

Comment: Add a submit button. Not all users know that pressing enter in a text input would submit a form, and if they are copy/pasting they might be using the mouse already so a button click would be faster than moving their hand to the Enter key. A submit button also signals the user that this is something that can be submitted.

Comment: @David Dorward my submit button is added by the jqueryUI dialog

Comment: That smells broken: http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion is..
Create a submit button. If you do not want to show the submit button, then hide the button using CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately, Chrome (v7.0.517.8 dev) seems to be clever enough to know the submit button is hidden and not listen to the enter key press :-(

Answer (score 2):

You could use the keyup event of jquery and if the key pressed is 13 (enter key code) then submit the form:

```
$('#input-id').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#form-id').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is also a good option but need to implement the keyup even for all elements. This will increase the workload to the browser as well as coding.

Comment: You could also implement this for all the elements using a class selector, but even though I agree your solution is cleaner and better.